# How to get content Controls from current selection in word add-in

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office365, office-js, word-addins

I am developing a word add-in using word JavaScript api. I want to get the content controls of the current selection. I have inserted the content control like below and it is working:

```
var range = context.document.getSelection();
var myContentControl = range.insertContentControl();
```

How can I get the content controls from a range object?

Please advice.

Comment: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range

Answer (score 2):

have you tried context.document.getSelection().contentControls; ?

remember to load the content control collection, here is some sample code....

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
      
        var myCCs = context.document.getSelection().contentControls;
        context.load(myCCs);

        return context.sync()

        .then(function(){
            for(var i=0; i< myCCs.items.length; i++){
                // here you will get the full content of content controls within the selection, 
                console.log("this is full  paragraph:" + (i + 1) + ":" + myCCs.items[i].text);

            }




        })
    });
```

**Adding more details to my original answer.**

My previous code sample returns all the content controls within the selection, it seems to be that what's needed is the content controls that are in the selected paragraph(s). This can be a partially selected paragraph (i.e. just the insertion point) or expand multiple paragraphs. This is a more 'complicated' scenario as this requires traversing a collection within a collection using promises patterns. Here is a code sample on how to achieve this hope this helps.

```js
Word.run(function(context) {
        //first we get the paragraphs on the selection.
        var myPars = context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
        context.load(myPars);  //note you need not to incldue scalar properties like title or tags, all scalars are included.
        return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
                // we have the paragraphs, now lets get the content controls for each paragraph (will only be one paragraph if the cursor is in any paragraph only)
                forEach(myPars,function(item, i){
                   var  myCCs = myPars.items[i].contentControls;
                    context.load(myCCs);
                    return context.sync()
                    .then(function(){
                           for (var j=0;j<myCCs.items.length;j++){
                               // here i am accessing each content control.
                                console.log(myCCs.items[j].text);
                           } 
                    })
                })
        })

 function forEach(collection, handler) {
        var promise = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function (resolve) { resolve(); });
        collection.items.forEach(function (item, index) {
            promise = promise.then(function () {
                return handler(item, index);
            })
        });
        return promise;
    }

        
        
    });
```

Comment: When i tried above "context.document.getSelection().contentControls;" word showing below Error:` {"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"PropertyNotLoaded","message":"The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object ....`.

Comment: sorry i thought it was obvious that the collection needed to be loaded.. i added more details to my answer, that should help you move fwd.. sorry and thanks!

Comment: Thanks @juan: it's returns no contentControl as i have a content control in current paragraph selection. Do i need to get the parentContentControl to get the content controls in current selection.

Comment: Sorry above code returns contentControl when i select the paragraph but not when my cursor is on paragraph, i want to get the all contentControl of a paragraph in **DocumentSelectionChanged** event. Please advice.

Comment: For that I would first get the paragraph collection within The selection, and then traverse it. For each paragraph get the content controls (each paragraph within the collection holds a contentControls collection)

Comment: Thankyou @Juan for your help. Can you please provide some sample code for above that will help me alot.

Comment: :i have added my code as answer, can you please check, am i followed the right steps? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the working code:

```
var range=context.document.getSelection().paragraphs;
context.load(range, 'text');
return context.sync()
.then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < range.items.length; i++) {
        context.load(range.items[i].contentControls, 'text,tag');
    }
})
.then(context.sync)
.then(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < range.items.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < range.items[i].contentControls.items.length; i++) {
            console.log("<br/>Content Control:" + (j + 1) + ":" + range.items[i].contentControls.items[j].text);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: just added more details to my original answer hopefully that will help you. note that you are not storing each of the content controls in variables that's why your code is failing. I think there is a simpler way to achieve this, check out my second sample.